# Spring Boot upgrade causing OAuth exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, access-token

Currently, I am working on upgrading Java and Spring Boot version for my application from Java 8 to Java 17 and then Spring Boot to 2.7.4.

With this upgrade, application started giving below exception while setting the access token.

I am passing the access token related information to another JAR which then retrieves the token information from token master.
Same configuration file worked with Java 8 and I am sure it is not corrupted. When I debug, I observed that Spring Boot is not able to parse ASCII space which was somehow handled in previous versions. Have anyone faced similar issue?

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: scope "audience:server:client_id:ADD_00000 AAA:drr:BADAM.SS_" contains invalid characters
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:121)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistration$Builder.validateScopes(ClientRegistration.java:706)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistration$Builder.build(ClientRegistration.java:625)
    at com.restclient.oauth2.SpringSecurityRequestInterceptor.createClientRegistration(SpringSecurityRequestInterceptor.java:165)
    at com.restclient.oauth2.SpringSecurityRequestInterceptor.<init>(SpringSecurityRequestInterceptor.java:59)
    at com.restclient.oauth2.OAuth2RequestInterceptor.<init>(OAuth2RequestInterceptor.java:38)
    at com.restclient.feign.FeignRestClientBuilder.setTokenAuthentication(FeignRestClientBuilder.java:156)
    at com.restclient.RestClientHolder.configureBuilder(RestClientHolder.java:275)
    at com.restclient.RestClientHolder.getBuilder(RestClientHolder.java:313)
    at com.restclient.RestClientHolder.getService(RestClientHolder.java:319)
    at com.restclient.RestHelper.getService(RestHelper.java:34)
    at com.restclient.RestHelper.getService(RestHelper.java:80)
```

Comment: yes... I updated error with proper exception

Comment: Your scope `audience:server:client_id:ADD_00000 AAA:drr:BADAM.SS_` is valid. Maybe there is an invisible char or an encoding problem. Show your `application.yml` containing this scope.